# Git branches default group permissions are set to user instead of group

Tags: linux, git, permissions

I am setting up GIT repos for my companies development teams, and I seem to be having an interesting issue.

Often times it arises that multiple people will have to work on the same branch, so when a branch is created and pushed to stage the other devs pull the branch into their local repos and begin working on the code. However the branch on our staging server in .git/logs/refs/heads has the permissions set for both user and group to the user that pushed the branch to our staging environment.

Is there a way to change this default behavior in GIT? We have a user group setup and when we manually change the group permissions on the branches we are able to push, but I'd rather not have a cron job running changing the permissions all the time.

In the image here you can see two repos that have had the permissions manually changed, and one that has just been pushed.

[image: List of GIT ranches and permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by the credentials of the process that creates new files, wether they are in the git repository or in the working copy.  And the possible credentials may be taken from the SSH session if push is over SSH, by the git server process if pushing over the custom git protocol, and so on.

You can't change the owner of a file unless you are root.  But you can enforce the group of newly created files by using [the SGID bit on directories](http://www.library.yale.edu/wsg/docs/permissions/sgid.htm).